# PrimeFaces uploadFile is not working

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>`. It does not invoke the listener method. If I add the `FileUploadFilter`, then I get an exception.

View:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload mode="advanced"
        fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload()}"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG)$/"
        auto="false" />
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
public class fileUploadController {

    private String destination = "c:\test";

    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile()
                .getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        // Do what you want with the file
        try {
            copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile()
                    .getInputstream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
        try {

            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination
                    + fileName));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            System.out.println("New file created!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Checkout this tutorial : http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/file-upload-with-primefaces

Comment: what's the exception you get? Is "Faces Servlet" the name of your jsf servlet? Otherwise you have to adjust the following line:

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

into 

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>NAME OF YOUR SERVLET HERE</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

Comment: Faces Servlet is not the name for my jsf servlet,

Comment: In future questions, always copypaste the entire exception. The exception is basically the whole answer to your problem. You should not ignore exceptions. If you're unable to understand what the exception is telling you, then you should just copypaste it so that we can explain it for you.

Comment: You have a fix 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262356/file-upload-doesnt-work-with-ajax-in-primefaces-4-0-running-on-jsf-2-2-x/19381134#19381134

Answer (score 0):

`fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload()}"` is problem here. I reproduced that and I also got an exception Method not found:

You should define fileUploadListener whithout parentheses. When you have added parentheses, expected method in your bean is upload() and not upload(FileUploadEvent event)