# Handling form data and file upload on same form using Primefaces fileUpload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form that contains some normal form input fields and then a file upload option. The file upload is optional however. When the users selects a file and clicks the upload button the form `enctype` must be set to `multipart/form-data` however if the user does not add a file but just clicks submit then the `enctype` must be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is the default. If the `enctype` is not set correctly I get errors on the submit. I have tried changing the `enctype` dynamically as the upload button it pressed but that doesn't seem to work.

My page:

```
<h:form id="master">
    ... some fields and other stuff

     <p:fileUpload value="#{controller.file}" mode="simple"/>
     <p:commandButton 
        onstart="document.getElementById('master').enctype = 'multipart/form-data';" 
        value="Upload" ajax="false" actionListener="#{controller.uploadFile}" />

     <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="submit" 
        actionListener="#{controller.buttonSubmit}"
        validateClient="true" ajax="false"/>
</h:form>
```

With this setup when I try to upload a file i get an error:

```
UT010016: Not a multi part request
```

If i move the `multipart/form-data` to the `h:form` tag then I can upload files, but I can't submit the page. Is there a way to upload files and handle a normal form submit on the same page? Or perhaps suggestions of another way to do it.

Comment: Try putting the p:fileUpload in a different h:form with enctype="multipart/form-data". That is the only way I achieve that.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't submit"? What happens when you try? It stands to reason that you can try to pull form data off the multipart request using the new servlet API's `Part` interface methods

Comment: I get the same error as mentioned `UT010016: Not a multi part request`

Answer (score 0):

Probably You are using WlidFly 8. 
Other application server (JBoss AS 6.1) work's fine for me with similar example.

Look at this https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6925

Comment: This solution was best for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262356/file-upload-doesnt-work-with-ajax-in-primefaces-4-0-jsf-2-2-x-javax-servlet-s/19752138#19752138