# custom p:fileUpload in p:dialog is not working

Tags: java, primefaces

I'm trying to use `<p:fileUpload>` inside `<p:dialog>`. 
When I use:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p:fileUpload mode="simple" id="file" value="#{hints.uploadedFile}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

everything is ok, but I need to use my own styles. So I'm trying this:

```
<p:dialog .... >    
    <h:form id="resourceDialogForm">    
        <div class="row">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="file-upload-panel">
                        <p:fileUpload mode="simple" id="file" value="#{hints.uploadedFile}" />
                        <div class="input-append input-group">
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <h:outputText value="#{text['resourceDialog.choose.file']}" />
                                </button>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <input class="input-large form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

It is working when I use it not in `<p:dialog>`, but in `<p:dialog>` when I click the button nothing is happening.
I've checked a lot of topics (e.g. [File upload doesn't work with AJAX in PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262356/file-upload-doesnt-work-with-ajax-in-primefaces-4-0-jsf-2-2-x-javax-servlet-s)) but I'm still not able to work it out. I've also tried to use advaced `<p:fileUpload>` with `dragDropSupport="true"` and `fileUploadListener`, but while drag and drop is working just fine, the button is not.

Comment: Do you have `<h:form>` around `<p:fileUpload>` when using dialog?

Comment: Yes, I have `<h:form>`. I've updated my question to show structure of my `<p:dialog>`.