# multipart/form-data enctype ignored

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, multipartform-data, enctype

I have defined a form as multipart/form-data enctype. When I press a command button the request is not send with 'multipart/form-data' content-type.

```
<h:form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <input type="file" ></input>

     <p:commandButton id="save" icon="saveBt" value="#{msgs.saveBt}" ... />

</h:form>
```

In the developer tools console I can see the Content-Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.

I'm working with JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 5.1.

Thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to upgrade JSF? "*I'm not using `<p:fileUpload>` because it doesn't work with ajax and mode attribute set to "simple"*". This is in fact required - `mode="simple"` always requires `ajax="false"` (It is a specified behaviour).

Comment: I suppose you are suggesting me to upgrade to 2.2 because of h:inputFile. I'm working with JBoss 7.1 (shipped with JSF 2.1) and I'm not sure if it would be possible to upgrade to JSF 2.2

Comment: I did not use JBoss either. Therefore, I am not sure about it, if it is compatible with JSF 2.2 (This is after all dependent upon Servlet version. JSF 2.2 requires at least Servlet 3.0 mainly because of `<h:inputFile>`). You could upgrade to JSF 2.2, if that version of JBoss (7.1) supports Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Probably it is possible to upgrade JBoss 7.1 to JSF 2,2, but I'm not sure if the client I'm developing for would permit to upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JSF and Primefaces, so use `<p:fileUpload>` instead of `<input type="file">`. Take a look at [official demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not using <p:fileUpload> because it doesn't work with ajax and mode attribute set to "simple". In fact, I've tried what @BalusC explain in http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html. But again, it doesn't work with ajax. I've seen that the problem is because the form is not submitted with 'multipart/form-data' content-type when the request is ajax type.

Comment: Does it work if you use `<h:commandButton>` instead of `<p:commandButton>`? Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262356/file-upload-doesnt-work-with-ajax-in-primefaces-4-0-jsf-2-2-x-javax-servlet-s) for more info, if you haven't already read it.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I've readed it before. Same result using a <h:commandButton>.